# Moving a sprite when mouse is pressed in Python

Tags: python, mouse, sprite, move, mouseclick-event

I'm making a Pong clone for learning purposes, and need to get the ball moving from the middle of the screen (it's sent there when it goes past a paddle) when the mouse is pressed. I've tried the following code,  but it does nothing, so I probably don't understand the syntax. Try to keep it as simple as possible please, and explain it, I'd rather not have 50 lines of code for this (I want to understand everything I'm using here). I think this is all the relevant code, sorry if it isn't. Thanks.

```
def middle(self):
    """Restart the ball in the centre, waiting for mouse click. """
    # puts ball stationary in the middle of the screen
    self.x = games.screen.width/2
    self.y = games.screen.height/2
    self.dy = 0
    self.dx = 0

    # moves the ball if mouse is pressed
    if games.mouse.is_pressed(1):
        self.dx = -3
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of library like pygame? Also the check for mouse being pressed happens once during the middle call(). If you mouse isn't pressed at that moment, the ball will not move.

Comment: I'm using livewires. I moved the code to Ball's update() function, but it still does nothing when I click the mouse. I'm convinced that I'm not asking if the mouse is pressed in the correc way.

Comment: Quite likely. Livewires doesn't seem to have anything by way of online documentation, so I can't look it up. But see if they have something for a mouse event handler. In which case you can try and set your `self.dx = -3` inside the mouse click event handler.

Comment: can you put a print statement before the `if` and actually see how many times is checking if the mouse is pressed?

Comment: I changed the code, using space bar to get the ball moving, and that worked fine, so I'm definitely asking if the mouse is pressed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know exactly what's happening based on that code fragment, but it looks like you are using the wrong function to detect whether or not the mouse button is pressed.

`Screen.is_pressed` from the games module wraps `pygame.key.get_pressed`, which only detects the state of keyboard keys, not mouse buttons.  You probably want the function `Screen.mouse_buttons`, which wraps `pygame.mouse.get_pressed`. You could use it within a loop like this (I'll pretend you have an instance of `games.Screen` called 'screen'):

```
left, middle, right = screen.mouse_buttons()
# value will be True if button is pressed
if left:
    self.dx = -3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the same issue as a beginner `Python` coder - `Games.py` (revision 1.7) includes several `is_pressed` methods in various classes, including both keyboard and mouse.

```
class Mouse(object):

#other stuff then 
def is_pressed(self, button_number):
    return pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[button_number] == 1
```

since pygame is a compiled module (I have 1.9.1) referring to the documentation rather than source code, I find [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pygame/latest/pygame.pdf) that there is a pygame.mouse.get_pressed(): 
the will get the state of the mouse buttons

```
get_pressed() -> (button1, button2, button3)
```

So I think the issue is the use of this in (y)our code rather than the use of the wrong function.....

OK GOT THIS TO WORK - MY FIX:

```
class myClass(games.Sprite):
    def update(self):
        if games.mouse.is_pressed(0)==1:
            self.x=games.mouse.x
            self.y=games.mouse.y
```

invoking the in Main() causes the selected sprite to move to the mouse location. HTH